# how to find the current page is isngle activity page in buddypress?

Tags: buddypress

I want to check whether the current page is "Single activity page" or not,

I ned like ths, `if(is_single_activity())`
or

```
if(is_page('is_single_activity'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
bp_is_single_activity()
```